# Firefox Extension How to call function / store any variable

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

How can i call function of my js script in Firefox extension

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Emailv",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "check email is vaild and update in database",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/email.png",
    "96": "icons/email.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.verifyemailaddress.org/*"],
      "js": ["Emailv.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Emaily.js have a function but it Firefox don't getting function and variable

```
var t = "free"; 
function keye(){
        var x = document.getElementById("nuuu").value;
        var iop = 109;
        x = x+1;
        //sessionStorage.setItem('key', x);
        var emai = document.querySelector("body > header > form > fieldset >input").value;
    
    }
console.log("start Now");

function fire(){
    document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
    console.log("start Now");
    document.body.onload = addElement;
    var start = document.querySelector("body > header ");
    start.innerHTML +='<div id="emailv" style="position:relative;margin:auto;width:100px;height:100px;opacity:0.3;z-index:100; background:#000;"><form><input id="nuuu" type="number"><button id="st" onclick="keye()" > Start</button></form><script></div>';
}
window.onload = fire();
```

I only received start now in console and whenever i try to get var t or try to function it has error Uncaught ReferenceError: keye is not defined and t no defined
as it say start now that mean java script run but don't hold any storage for var or function

I add element and add inner HTML and set onclick function and there i run this function.

Comment: Where from are you trying to access `keye() & `t`?

Comment: @erosman 
I add element and add inner HTML and set onclick function and there i run this function. updated same in question also.

Answer (score 1):

["content_scripts"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) default `run_at` is `"document_idle"` which means the document and all its resources have finished loading.

`window.onload` will not fire for your script since script is injected after `window` `'load'`. It is not needed anyway.

Here is an example...

```js
console.log('Starting the code');

const t = "free"; 

// run fire();
fire();

function fire(){
  
  console.log('fire called');
  document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
  document.body.onload = addElement;
  const start = document.querySelector("body > header ");
  start.innerHTML += '<div id="emailv" style="position:relative;margin:auto;width:100px;height:100px;opacity:0.3;z-index:100; background:#000;"><form><input id="nuuu" type="number"><button id="st"> Start</button></form><script></div>';
}

function keye() {
  
  let x = document.getElementById("nuuu").value;
  const iop = 109;
  x = x+1;
  //sessionStorage.setItem('key', x);
  const emai = document.querySelector("body > header > form > fieldset > input").value;
}
```

**Update on Comment**

Please note that Page JavaScript is isolated from Content JavaScript for security. They run in different context/scope.

When you create a DOM, like `<button id="st" onclick="keye()"> Start</button>`and inject it into the page DOM, the `onclick="keye()"` will belong to page JavaScript. Obviously, page JavaScript can not access the `function keye()` which is in the content scope.

You would need to add the `onclick` in content scope if you want to run a function in the content scope.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector('#st').addEventListener('click', keye);
```

Now the `'click'` will run `keye()` in content scope.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: keye is not defined
    onclick https://www.verifyemailaddress.org/?#result:1
Still error can you help me

Comment: @PuneetSharma I will explain it in the post.